# Поиск и сортировка по датафреймам Pandas в запутанной таблице

Tags: python, pandas, таблицы, автоматизация

имеется 2 таблицы exel выгнанные из базы 1C в стремном формате, требуется каким-то образом вычленить нужные данные и создать новый эксель только с ними.[image]

Требуется достать все данные под HOWO В787НТ,HOWO Т488ЕТ, Sitrak О243КС. Проблема в том, что они разбросаны. Может быть надпись HOWO В787НТ и указаны 3 ячейки с весом, а чуть ниже еще такая же надпись допустим 1 ячейка, и плюсом во втором exel файле ровно та же история. Как автоматически все это объеденить в одну большую таблицу?[image: .]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал какой-то супер простенький код, который хотябы создает отдельную таблицу без лишней верхней информации
В идеале надо сделать чтобы по нажатию, или даже просто каждые 24 часа приложение само скачивало с почты присланные 2-е таблицы от определенного человека, доставало все нужное, объеденяла и создавала эксель и пдф результата.
За данную помощь могу заплатить, просто главное сделать, а то каждый день заниматься этим вычленение информации на протяжении пары лет как-то лень... Заранее спасибо. По этой ссылке можно скачать примеры этих exel таблиц: "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V2eZAyibQFAAqHv3U08JIm-vgFqK6OJY?usp=drive_link"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог (раз уж вы целиком скопировали его в следующий свой вопрос), отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, сначала данные нужно готовить, а потом с ними работать. в вашем случае можно сделать так (первый файл из примера, ищем все вхождения `MERCEDES №6 В616ХУ АЛМАЗ`):

```
# читаем файл, пропускаем заголовки и последнюю строку
df = pd.read_excel("04-05.11 (1).xls", skiprows=10, skipfooter=1)
src_str = "MERCEDES №6 В616ХУ АЛМАЗ"

# меняем все порядковые номера после названия модели на это самое название
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].mask(df.iloc[:,0].astype(str).str.isdigit()).ffill()
# убираем строки без данных
df = df.dropna(thresh=6)
# выбираем ряды, в которых название равно нашей строке
res = df[df.iloc[:,0]==src_str]
```

res:

```
                    Смена №2  Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  3590.05
7   MERCEDES №6 В616ХУ АЛМАЗ         NaN   20:20:34         NaN       63.65   20:28:06       21.40    42.25
8   MERCEDES №6 В616ХУ АЛМАЗ         NaN   22:00:47         NaN       62.45   22:11:22       21.35    41.10
9   MERCEDES №6 В616ХУ АЛМАЗ         NaN   23:43:14         NaN       57.30   23:52:20       21.35    35.95
10  MERCEDES №6 В616ХУ АЛМАЗ         NaN    1:37:48         NaN       67.00    1:44:53       21.35    45.65
```